# Netsuite SuiteTalk - Login

Tags: suitetalk

I am trying to use SuiteTalk to retrieve customer records.

I downloaded the v2016.1 WSDL from here: http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/resources/suitetalk-documentation.shtml

I used mv package to build the WSDL and generated the jar file.

I create a project in Eclipse and added the jar file. I am using Java.

Here's a snippet of my code. I am stuck here and don't know how to proceed. It looks like I am missing another jar file? like the NetSuiteService?

`RecordRef role = new RecordRef();`
`role.setInternalId("3");`
`role.setType(RecordType.contact);`
`Passport passport = new Passport();`
`passport.setEmail("me@test.com");`
`passport.setPassword("mypassword");`
`passport.setRole(role);`
`passport.setAccount("123456");`

Please help me. What do I need to do?

Comment: Do you have some sample code for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Java bindings, but it looks like you are missing the data center URL configuration.

I'd recommend using [the ruby bindings](https://github.com/netsweet/netsuite#configuration). They are community supported and there's some decent example code demonstrating various common functions.

Answer (score 0):

I work with .net, I think you need to initialize the service to indicate the datacenter that corresponds to you, it is more or less like this:

```
    // Instantiate the NetSuite web services
    Service = new Aggregates.DataCenterAwareNetSuiteService(_account);
    Service.Timeout = 1000 * 60 * 60;

    var appInfo = new ApplicationInfo();
    //App info from application netsuite
    appInfo.applicationId = cuenta.ApplicationInfo;

    // Prepare login credentials for request level login
    Service.passport = new Passport()
    {
        email = _email,
        password = _password,
        account = _account
    };

    Service.applicationInfo = appInfo;
```